# How to split each column into its own data frame?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 3 columns, for example:

```
my.data <- data.frame(A=c(1:5), B=c(6:10), C=c(11:15))
```

I would like to split each column into its own data frame (so I'd end up with a list containing three data frames). I tried to use the "split" function but I don't know what I would set as the factor argument. I tried this:

```
data.split <- split(my.data, my.data[,1:3])
```

but that's definitely wrong and just gives me a bunch of empty data frames. It sounds fairly simple but after searching through previous questions I haven't come across a way to do this.

Comment: `lapply(my.data, data.frame)`, then adjust names accordingly

Comment: More info on Sotos' answer: [What is the algorithm behind R core's `split` function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52158589/4891738)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why you'd want to do that; `lapply` let's you already operate on the columns directly; but you could do

```
lst <- split(t(my.data), 1:3);
names(lst) <- names(my.data);
lst;
#$A
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5
#
#$B
#[1]  6  7  8  9 10
#
#$C
#[1] 11 12 13 14 15
```

Turn `vector` entries into `data.frame`s with

```
lapply(lst, as.data.frame);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `split.default`, i.e.

```
split.default(my.data, seq_along(my.data))


$`1`
  A
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5

$`2`
   B
1  6
2  7
3  8
4  9
5 10

$`3`
   C
1 11
2 12
3 13
4 14
5 15
```